# Odd behavior with split in perl when result includes empty strings

Tags: perl, split

This is my perl 5.16 code

```
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  @data = split /a/, $_;
  print(join("b",@data),"\n");
}
```

If I input a file with this in it:

```
paaaa
paaaaq
```

I get

```
p
pbbbbq
```

But I was expecting

```
pbbbb
pbbbbq
```

Why am I wrong to expect the latter behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) that trailing empties are removed unless you specify a third, non-zero argument.

> If `LIMIT` is omitted (or, equivalently, zero), then it is usually treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that trailing empty fields are stripped (empty leading fields are always preserved)

You want

```
split /a/, $_, -1;
```

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: it's a complicated bit of documentation; the only excuse for it is that it almost always does what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the LIMIT parameter in the split perldoc:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

The relevant section is:

> If LIMIT is negative, it is treated as if it were instead arbitrarily large; as many fields as possible are produced.
>
> If LIMIT is omitted (or, equivalently, zero), then it is usually treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that trailing empty fields are stripped (empty leading fields are always preserved); if all fields are empty, then all fields are considered to be trailing (and are thus stripped in this case).

So to get the behavior you're expecting, try:

```
while(<>) {
  chomp;
  @data = split /a/, $_, -1;
  print(join("b",@data),"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because after splitting *paaaa* , you got an array *@data* that has only one elemet *p* in it.
Maybe substitution is better:

```
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    $_=~s/a/b/g;
    print($_,"\n");
}
```